# WinJS - Unable to get property 'forEach' of undefined or null reference

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I'm working on my 1st WinJS app for Windows 8 and I'm just trying to replace the base code given in 2 grid template and I'm getting this error:

```
Unable to get property 'forEach' of undefined or null reference
```

My code:

```
getData().forEach(function (item) {
    list.push(item);
});
```

The initial function:

```
function getData() {

    // JSON request
    WinJS.xhr({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://mytld.com/mobile/pagethatreturnsjsondata.php"
    }).then(
            function (response) {
                OnSuccessCall(response);
            },
            function (error) {
                var err = error;
                console.log("Error : " + err.message);
            },
            function (progress) { }
    );
}
```

The following is getting the data from a php webservice which is returning JSON data:

```
function OnSuccessCall(response) {
    var itemContent = "<p>Item Content</p>";
    var itemDescription = "Item Description";
    var groupDescription = "Group Description";

    // These three strings encode placeholder images. You will want to set the
    // backgroundImage property in your real data to be URLs to images.
    var darkGray = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAANSURBVBhXY3B0cPoPAANMAcOba1BlAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";
    var lightGray = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAANSURBVBhXY7h4+cp/AAhpA3h+ANDKAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";
    var mediumGray = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAANSURBVBhXY5g8dcZ/AAY/AsAlWFQ+AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";

    // Each of these sample groups must have a unique key to be displayed separately.
    var sampleGroups = [
        { key: "group1", title: "prayers", subtitle: "submitted prayers", backgroundImage: darkGray, description: groupDescription }
    ];

    var x = response.responseText.length;
    var json = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
    var sampleItems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length - 1; i++) {
        sampleItems.push({
            group: sampleGroups[0],
            title: json[i].text,
            subtitle: "Item Subtitle: 1",
            description: itemDescription,
            content: itemContent,
            backgroundImage: lightGray
        });
    }

    return sampleItems;
}
```

I'm able to see data in sampleItems:

[image: watch window with object data]

I'm obviously doing something wrong, as when I compare my object results with the results from the original example data they are virtually the same.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your `getData` function returned `null` or `undefined`. That's what the error message is telling you. You shared the code for the wrong function.

Comment: getData calls OnSuccessCall - I'll add the getData function for clarity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getData()` function does not have a `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`. And you cannot `forEach` on `undefined`.

Looking at the bigger picture: Your `getData()` uses `xhr`, so it does not actually return the results, Instead, it gets the data asynchronously. You therefore cannot `forEach` the return value because the results don't exist yet. You have to wait for the promise to complete, and then you can call `forEach` on the promise result.

```
function getData() {
    // add "return" here so the function returns a Promise
    return WinJS.xhr({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://mytld.com/mobile/pagethatreturnsjsondata.php"
    }).then(
            function (response) {
                // add "return" here to specify the promise's completed value
                return OnSuccessCall(response);
            },
            function (error) {
                var err = error;
                console.log("Error : " + err.message);
            },
            function (progress) { }
    );
}
```

Now that `getData()` returns something (a Promise) you can schedule work to occur when the promise completes.

```
getData().then(function(results) { results.forEach(...) });
```